# modal form not submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was looking for a way to keep my modal form open after submit and I manage to do that but now my problem is the submit form is not submiting the value. Is there somthing wrong with my jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<form class="needs-validation" id="contact-form" action="index13.php" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <label>Date:</label>  
        <span id="date1" name="date"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <label>Time:</label> 
        <span id="clock1" name="time"></span>
    </div>  
    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5" style="margin-top: 05px;">
        <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
        <input type="text" id="username2" name="username2" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
        <label for="modalUsername">Username</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="margin-left: 30px">
            Enter username.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-4">
        <i class="fa fa-lock prefix"></i>
        <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
        <label for="modalPassowrd">Password</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="margin-left: 30px">
            Enter password.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mb-3">
        <button type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Log out <i class="fa fa-sign-out ml-1"></i></button>
    </div>

    <!--Footer-->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="options text-center text-md-right mt-1">
            <p class="font-small blue-text d-flex justify-content-end" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPush">
                Forgot <a href="#" class="blue-text ml-1" style="margin-right: 310px;">Password?</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

php inside index13:

```
<?php
    include_once ('connection.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username2 = $_POST['username2'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
        $time = date("H:i:s");
        $sql = "select * from visitor_att where uname = '$username2' and pass = '$password1'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count == 0) {
            echo "No Results";
        } else {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $username2 = $row['uname'];
                $password1 = $row['pass'];
                $fname=$row['fname'];
                $lname=$row['lname'];   
                $InsertSql = "Update visitor_att set timeout = '$time' where uname = '$username2' and pass = '$password1'";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $InsertSql); 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the script is use to prevent my modal form from refreshing after submit:

```
    <script>    
$(function() {


 var frm = $("#contact-form");

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr("method"),
            url: frm.attr("action"),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
           });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Updated my jQuery code, still not submiting. i try to run it 
on console, it says submission was successful but no data

Comment: Password should not be stored in plain text. Should be salted and encrypted.

Comment: I think you have to use some ajax solution to do this thing. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: As @Endless mentioned, PHP provides [``password_hash()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [``password_verify()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. Also your script is wide open to SQL injection attacks. So when you get your form-submit-through-ajax working, please do look into [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Are you sure you have only one form in the page? Maybe better to use `$('form#contact-form').serialize()`

Comment: There is a syntax error in your PHP code. What does the random `</script>` tag do there?

Comment: @Mojtaba i have more than 1 form in the page sir. i tried $('form#contact-form').serialize() but still not submiting to database

Comment: @jrswgtr sorry about that , wrong editing my code but i remove it now  sir

Comment: What’s the id for the other forms? All your ids must be different

Comment: the other forms have no id just this form has an id

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: @MegaColorBoy, its not updating the data on my database, it's like the submit button not inserting, itried puting this code  success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }  and it shows no data

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with server side code i.e PHP code.

On server side PHP code you have written a condition i.e if the request contains `$_POST['submit']` key then insert the data in the database otherwise do nothing.

Here is the JSFiddle where i tried this code https://jsfiddle.net/g2b4ujzp/1/. Go to the fiddle open developer tools of the browser go to network tab, click the log out button. There you will see that there is no value with the key `submit` in the request.

You are serializing the form and sending the data but the `form.serialize()` method does not serializes the button elements. hence the `submit` named input doesn't serialize causing the condition `isset($_POST['submit'])` false on server side.

I would suggest you to write an `else` code block for the condition `isset($_POST['submit'])` to debug by printing some error. And on client add a hidden input element named `submit` with some value.